# How would I find the least exponent of this problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

Least exponent, meaning to factor by the lowest exponent. With that said the problem I am having trouble with is...

$$
\mathrm{y}\left(x\right) =
\frac{\sqrt{1 - \ln^{2}\left(x\right)} - x\left(-\,{1 \over 2}\right)
\left[1 - \ln^{2}\left(x\right)\right]^{-1/2}(-2\ln\left(x\right)/x)}
{1 - \ln^{2}\left(x\right)}
$$

The only thing that I see that are common in the numerator are the
$\sqrt{1 - \ln^{2}\left(x\right)}$ and
$\left[1 - \ln^{2}\left(x\right)\right]^{-1/2}$. So then I would factor out the one with the lower exponent which would be the
$\left[1 - \ln^{2}\left(x\right)\right]^{-1/2}$ and the reason for that is because $\sqrt{1 - \ln^{2}\left(x\right)}$ becomes $\left[1 - \ln^{2}\left(x\right)\right]^{1/2}$ which has an exponent of $1/2$. The factored out $\left[1 - \ln^{2}\left(x\right)\right]^{-1/2}$ would then go in the denominator because it is negative and that is why the denominator in the answer is $\sqrt{\left[1 - \ln^{2}\left(x\right)\right]^{3}}$. After that, I'm not sure what to do next.

And the answer is supposed to be...
$$
\mathrm{y}\left(x\right) =
\frac{\left(-1\right)\left[lnx^2x - \ln\left(x\right) - 1\right]}
{\sqrt{\left[1 - \ln^{2}\left(x\right)\right]^{3}}}
$$

Comment: i have got this here $$\frac{-2 \log ^2(x)+\log (x)+2}{2 \left(1-\log ^2(x)\right)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: I didn't change $lnx^2x$ because I didn't understand it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a slightly different approach to  simplify the expression.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> y(x)&=\frac{\sqrt{1-\ln^2x}-x({-\frac12})(1-\ln^2x)^{-\frac12}(-2(\ln x)*\frac1x)}{1-\ln^2x}\\
> &=\frac{\sqrt{1-\ln^2x}-\ln x(1-\ln^2x)^{-\frac 12}}{1-\ln^2x}\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{\sqrt{1-\ln^2x}-\ln x(1-\ln^2x)^{-\frac 12}}{1-\ln^2x}\cdot\frac{(1-\ln^2x)^{\frac 12}}{(1-\ln^2x)^{\frac 12}}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1-\ln^2 x-\ln x}{\sqrt{(1-\ln^2x)^{3}}}\\
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we simplify the numerator  by doing some cancellation.
- In (2)  it is  convenient to expand numerator  and  denominator with $(1-\ln^2x)^{\frac 12}$. Note that 
  \begin{align*}
  \sqrt{1-\ln^2x}\cdot(1-\ln^2x)^{\frac 12}&=1-\ln^2 x\\
  (1-\ln^2x)^{-\frac 12}\cdot(1-\ln^2x)^{\frac 12}&=1
  \end{align*}